# to permanent the limit of CPU Scaling settings

Tags: 14.04, performance, cpu

I'm using intel core i3 with 2.2 GHz clock. I want to limit my CPU usage to 2GHz with command:

```
cpupower frequency-set -u 2GHz
```

and when I check with `cpufreq-info' state of CPU change into 2GHz.

but when I reboot, the state is reset again.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of accomplishing this. One way is to edit the file `/etc/rc.local` using sudo powers. Add your command just before the last line:

```bash
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

cpupower frequency-set -u 2GHz

exit 0
```

If this doesn't work at first ensure the `/etc/rc.local` file is an executable using:

```bash
$ ll /etc/rc.local
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 944 Jan  5 11:57 /etc/rc.local*
```

Note the 3 x's appearing near the beginning of the line. This means the script can be executed by the owner, the group and anyone else.